# How to create windows service for JBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: jboss-eap-6

I have migrated from JBoss 6.2 WAP to EAP 6.4
I am not able create jboss as a service. Service is installed successfully but unable to run the service. [image]

The same is working fine with JBoss EAP 6.2.  Does JBoss 6.4 EAP support jbosssvc.exe. Is it possible to configure services?

Answer (score 0):

In the JBoss EAP 6.2 installation guide, there is a section "Configure JBoss EAP 6 as a Service in Microsoft Windows Server". All the information you need is there. In case you cannot find it, you can follow the link below:

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html-single/Installation_Guide/index.html#Install_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform_6_Microsoft_Windows_Service

Comment: Thank You  @Panagiotis Chavariotis http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/run-jboss-as-service-howto

Comment: Thank You  @Panagiotis Chavariotis. But we want it the way specified  here which is not working http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/run-jboss-as-service-howto

Comment: My recommendation is to stick with the official documentation.